# Java Script: Using Same Instance in two diffrent .js

Tags: javascript

How can I use same instance of one particula .js across all .js functions

For eg: var test = new Test();

this test i need to use when ever I want to access Test() function(i.e same instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little on what exactly your code looks like, but:

```
window['test'] = new Test();
```

should generally do the trick. After that, any scripts in your page should be able to see "test" as a global variable, which is the same as being a property of the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply omit the `var` part and make it a globally accessible instance of Test() like this.

```
test = new Test();
```

**EDIT:** Sorry I didn't see that you need it across functions.